# linq findlast and where difference

Tags: linq

I want to know that what is the difference between execution of these in term of database hit? Because of ToList() extension method what is the outcome of the first and the second query

```
List widgetdet = (from gid in GetWidgetMetas(SidebarDetailsId)
                 select gid).ToList();

var str=(widgetdet.FindLast(p => p.vcr_key == "ShowThumbnail").vcr_value // (1)

var str=widgetdet.Where(p => p.vcr_key == "txttitle").First().vcr_value  // (2)
```

Comment: What is the return type of `GetWidgetMetas(SidebarDetailsId)` ?

Answer (score 1):

I can't be positive, since I can't see what `GetWidgetMetas()` is doing, but assuming that it is returning an IQueryable<>, then the database will be hit when `.ToList()` is called.

The database will not be hit for the `FindLast` and `Where` methods since `widgetdet` is the complete list in memory at that point.